# How to move current arrow away from the component?

Tags: circuitikz

This is what my outcome is and cannot seem to figure hw to move the arrow of the inductor away from the inductor

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american, straight voltages]
\draw (0,0)
    to [american voltage source, v=$V_P$, invert, voltage shift=1] (0,4) %Input voltage  Vp
    to [R=$R_p$] (3,4)
    to [R=$R_L$] (6,4)
    to [L, l_=$L$, v^<=$v_L$, i=$i_L$, voltage shift=1.5] (7,4)
    
    to [Tnigbt,bodydiode] (11,4)
    to [short] (13,4)
    to [american voltage source, v^<=$V_{out}$, voltage shift=1] (13,0)
    to [short] (0,0)
    
    
    
    (3,4) to [R=$R_Ci$] (3,1.5)
    to [C, l_=$C_i$, v^<=$v_{Ci}$] (3,0)
    
    (7.75,4) to [Tnigbt,bodydiode, invert] (7.75,0)
    
    (10.5,4) to [R=$R_Co$] (10.5,1.5)
    to [C, l_=$C_o$, v^<=$v_{Co}$] (10.5,0)
    
    (11,5) node[align=center]{$G_2$}
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Suggestion: If you set the style to `american`, you can use just `V` instead of `american voltage source`....

Comment: If I do that, the voltage symbol displayed in the circuitikz will be a circle with the circuit line straight through and no positive or negative sign in the voltage source.

Comment: Hmmm... yes. You should use `[straight voltages, american]`. It smells like a bug... I'll check, thanks

Comment: Ok, it is clearly an unwanted interaction, but it's been like that since day one, so changing it will just complicate things. I will comment in the documentation that `american` and `european` should go last... (mumble)

Comment: Please look at https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/671 (thanks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inductor needs more space.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}    

\begin{circuitikz}[american, straight voltages]
    \draw (0,0)
    to [american voltage source, v=$V_P$, invert, voltage shift=1] (0,4) %Input voltage  Vp
    to [R=$R_p$] (2,4)
    to [R=$R_L$] (4,4)
    to [L, l_=$L$, v^<=$v_L$, i=$i_L$, voltage shift=1.5] (7,4)
    
    to [Tnigbt,bodydiode] (10,4)
    to [short] (12,4)
    to [american voltage source, v^<=$V_{out}$, voltage shift=1] (12,0)
    to [short] (0,0)
        
    (2.0,4) to [R=$R_Ci$] (2.0,1.5)
    to [C, l_=$C_i$, v^<=$v_{Ci}$] (2.0,0)
    
    (7.2,4) to [Tnigbt,bodydiode, invert] (7.2,0)
    
    (10.0,4) to [R=$R_Co$] (10.0,1.5)
    to [C, l_=$C_o$, v^<=$v_{Co}$] (10.0,0)
    
    (11,5) node[align=center]{$G_2$}
    ;
\end{circuitikz}    

\end{document}
```

Add `\draw[help lines,red,thin,dotted] (-1,0) grid (14,5);`

to display the helper lines.